# Windows Git to Linux Remote

Tags: git

I'm not certain what I am doing wrong. In the past I used to use Zend Studio and it handled everything Git related for me and still does as of this moment. But I'm dropping Zend Studio and doing things by hand now.

My current setup is Windows 8 and I've installed the Git Windows binaries on my machine. I am able to commit to the local repository without any problems.

On my Remote Linux machine I've got the repositories setup there and I am able to pull from the repository without any problems.

On the Linux machine I start Git like this:
`/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-daemon --verbose --export-all --base-path=/usr/local/git/repository --base-path-relaxed --listen=git.sitegoodies.net --enable=receive-pack`

and it returns `[1619] Ready to rumble`

On my Windows machine I've committed a few changes and now I want to push them to my remote repository and I do it like this: `git push git://git.sitegoodies.net/test.git master`

I can see the following:

```
$ git push git://git.sitegoodies.net/test.git master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6)
```

But now it just sits there. So I look at my linux console from when I started Git and I can see this:

```
[1619] Ready to rumble
[1622] Connection from [fd35:4776:6804:1::1]:58695
[1622] Extended attributes (26 bytes) exist <host=git.sitegoodies.net>
[1622] Request receive-pack for '/test.git'
```

So to me it looks like everything should be working. Except everything just sits there until I Ctrl + C to cancel it from pushing to my remove repository. I really have no idea what is wrong, so I'm hoping someone here has an idea I can try.

I do not have any firewall.

My repositories are located in /usr/local/git/repository
To create test.git:

- I CD'd into my repository directory, `mkdir test.git`
- CD into test.git directory and run `git --bare init`

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that — [pushing to `git-daemon` is broken in Git for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=457). All attempts made to this day to debug this problem have failed.

So your best bet is to use SSH transport, I suppose — [this is not hard](http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/index.html).

Comment: @Diemuzi, also I hope you understand clearly that `git-daemon` provides zero authentication, so by allowing pushing via them you opened your repositories to anyone able to connect to the daemon's port.  Of course, you might be in a controlled environment, but I wanted to make sure there's no misunderstanding on your part.

Comment: Yes my setup is currently confined to my local network as I have no outside connection to worry about. This is another reason why I listed I currently have no firewall. Everything is strictly local only.

Comment: @Diemuzi, in any case, pushing works okay when exchange happens mediated by an SSH client (or using `libcurl`, in case you're working over HTTP[S] transport) but hangs if it happens over plain Windows socket. No one knows why exactly.

Comment: @Diemuzi, by the way, are your starting `git-daemon` directly or via `inetd`?

Comment: Interesting, I've been pulling my hair out over this for a few hours now trying to figure out why my old Zend Studio would work, but command line wouldn't. It's all becoming clear now. I don't mind using SSH either to make this work. I was simply used to "one" way. Very helpful, thank you =)

Comment: @Diemuzi, I think Zend Studio works because supposedly it uses JGit which is a pure Java library.

Comment: Yup, thank you again for the quick response. Everything appears to be working now =)